# React Native TextInput loses focus on call hook from useState

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, styled-components

**Environment**

react-native: "0.61.5",

"styled-components": "4.4.1"

**Reproduction**

Snack example: https://snack.expo.io/BJSfYqlCS

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {View} from 'react-native'

export default () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

  const StyledInput = styled.TextInput`
    background-color: red;
    border-color: black;
  `

  return (
    <View>
      <StyledInput value={text} onChangeText={text => setText(text)} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Steps to reproduce**

type something in styled TextInput

**Expected Behavior**

Just plain typing

**Actual Behavior**

lost focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get styles out of function

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {View} from 'react-native'

const StyledInput = styled.TextInput`
    background-color: red;
    border-color: black;
  `

export default () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <View>
      <StyledInput value={text} onChangeText={text => setText(text)} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Check [expo shack](https://snack.expo.io/rkJnDl-0B)

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is pretty tricky , It looks like the problem is that you're defining your StyledInput inside it's parent return method and then calling the parent's setText method directly (instead of passing through props), which causes rerender that you don't want.

Better approach would be to use direct text input and apply styling to it. Please see below code and also ive shared a working example in expo snack. do check that.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {TextInput,View} from 'react-native';

export default () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

  const StyledView = styled.View`
    flex: 1;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: papayawhip;
  `

  const StyledInput = styled.TextInput`
    background-color: white;
  `

  const StyledText = styled.Text`
    color: palevioletred;
  `

  return (
    <View>
      <StyledText>Hello World!</StyledText>
      <TextInput style={{height:50,width:50,backgroundColor:'red'}} value={text} onChangeText={text => setText(text)} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

expo snack [expo url](https://snack.expo.io/B19aNjlRr)

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts